# Sitecore MVC routing to resolve a hyphenated name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to get Sitecore MVC routing to give me content from the path of

> /Home/Test Url/With Space

from the URL:

> /test-url/with-space

So I need Sitecore to be able to recognise the URL has a hyphen, but can still resolve to the path without a hyphen.

Here is what I have so far:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Hyphenated URL",
   url: "test-url/{valuename}",
   defaults: new { scItemPath = "/Home/Test Url/{valuename}" });
```

This works with a path of:

> /test-url/with space

but if I add the hyphen in between "with" and "space", I can't get it to resolve. I'm guessing I need a custom route processor. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom route.

```
routes.MapHyphenatedRoute(
    name: "Hyphenated URL",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { scItemPath = "/Home/{controller}/{action}" }
    );
```

The idea here is to intercept route values with hyphens and translate them to your desired format. URLs without hyphens would remain untouched. **Sitecore** would still need the ability to handle the `scItemPath`.

```
public static class RouteCollectionExtensions
{
    public static Route MapHyphenatedRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults)
    {
        var route = new HyphenatedRoute(url, defaults);
        routes.Add(name, route);
        return route;
    }
}

public class HyphenatedRoute : Route
{
    public HyphenatedRoute(string url, object defaults) :
        base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
    { }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var routeData = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);

        if (routeData != null)
        {
            RouteValueDictionary values = routeData.Values;
            values["controller"] = Dehyphenate(values["controller"] as string);
            values["action"] = Dehyphenate(values["action"] as string);
        }

        return routeData;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext ctx, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        values["controller"] = Hyphenate((values["controller"] as string));
        values["action"] = Hyphenate(values["action"] as string);
        return base.GetVirtualPath(ctx, values);
    }

    private static string Hyphenate(string value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.IndexOf(' ') >= 0)
        {
            return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToLower(value.Replace(' ', '-'));
        }

        return value;
    }

    private static string Dehyphenate(string value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.IndexOf('-') >= 0)
        {
            return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(value.Replace('-', ' '));
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Your scenario may need different handling, but this code might help if you need route translation.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore 7 handles this out of the box, but in Sitecore 6.x you will need to add the following to the `<encodeNameReplacements>` element in your web.config:

`<replace mode="on" find=" " replaceWith="-" />`

This will basically tell Sitecore to map hyphens in the URL to spaces in the item's name.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd already added this element, but it didn't fix the issue.